# Replacing last 32 character in an item in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

sorry I tried to search about the topic and couldn't find what I need.

I have a table Called **Products** inside of it I have column called **Serial** and it's VARBINARY 64

I want to replace last 16 character/letter 1 item name **Product_1**

for example serial number in product_1 is

1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678900000

I want to change last 16 letter to be

123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I hope if you can help in a simple way )

thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's stopping you? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Also, are you *really* using SQL Server 2008? It has been long unsupported.

Comment: But binary <> character. "xxxx" are not valid binary or hexadecimal (which is just a condensed version of binary presentation) digits. Is this a presentation issue or do you actually need to change the binary value stored in your column?

Comment: @smor, yes I want to change the data stored in the column, but only replacing last part

Answer (score 0):

Query example for you:

```
select (substring(t1.code, 1, len(t1.code)-16) + 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as newcode from (
    select '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678900000' as code
) t1
```